# using javascript code while pasting the text with some formats new line is also inserted how to resolve it

Tags: javascript

i am new to javascripting i am using my copy contents code i am copying the text with some rich text formating and pasting in between some text where some other rich formatting is applied then while pasting using the below code some time it is inserting new line in between the text how to resolve that

```
function CopyContents() {
        var finalnode;
        if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
            var sel = window.getSelection();
            docFrag = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneContents();
            var ndd = docFrag.cloneNode(true);
            var par = sel.getRangeAt(0).startContainer;
            docFrag = extractNodesWithStyle(par.parentNode,ndd);
        }
    }



function PasteContents() {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        var Node = sel.focusNode; 
        var rang = sel.getRangeAt(0);
        if(rang.endOffset < Node.nodeValue.length) {
            var srange = document.createRange();
            srange.setStart(Node,rang.endOffset);
            srange.setEnd(Node,Node.nodeValue.length);
            var df = srange.extractContents();
            var ndd = df.firstChild.cloneNode(false);
            df = extractNodesWithStyle(sel.focusNode.parentNode,ndd);
            var par = Node.parentNode;
            var ns = par.nextSibling;
            par.parentNode.insertBefore( df, par.nextSibling );
            par.parentNode.insertBefore( docFrag.cloneNode(true), par.nextSibling );
        }else {
            Node.parentNode.insertBefore( docFrag.cloneNode(true), Node.nextSibling );
        }       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using regex to get rid of the spaces? Apply that regex on the item you want to get rid of the spacing. In the example below, the str is the string you want to remove the newlines from.

```
 str.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
```

Comment: thank for the reply but i didnot get exactly how to do that can u help me

Comment: got another issue with same code the issue is if i have a text Hi How are you with bold italic and bule colour formating and i am pasting hello which is plain text in between the formatted text then the plain hello is also getting the destination formatting except the last applied format please help me